# I need to print the third column of the LM Hash. But Python shows error at colon used after FS

Tags: python, awk, hash, subprocess

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import sys
def main():
    h = sys.argv[1]
    print ("This is an LM Hash.")
    cmd1 = 'awk 'BEGIN{FS =":"} {print $3}' <<< "+h" > lmhash.txt'
    data1 = subprocess.check_output(cmd1, shell=True)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Potential input to the above script:
bill007:500:EA0A545D9969EE58AAD3B435B51404EE:642CD60957BE48DA947B5AC779C40432:::

Comment: Check the 're' module of Python.  Using awk inside Python under a subprocess is adding to much unneeded complexity to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `split` for that :

```
import sys

def main():
    h = sys.argv[1]
    if len(h.split(':')) == 7 : 
        print("This is an LM Hash.")
        print(h.split(':')[2])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output :

```
This is an LM Hash.  
EA0A545D9969EE58AAD3B435B51404EE
```